# Dealing with multiple JSON result sets in R

Tags: json, r

I'm trying to get some JSON data of NBA box scores. The issue I'm having is that the JSON data for the box score has three result sets and I only care about one of them.

```
test<- "http://stats.nba.com/stats/boxscoretraditionalv2?EndPeriod=10&
       EndRange=14400&GameID=0021500580&RangeType=2&Season=2015-16&
       SeasonType=Regular+Season&StartPeriod=1&StartRange=0000"

library(jsonlite)

json_data <- fromJSON(paste(readLines(test), collapse=""))
str(json_data)
```

I really only care about the result set with the name "PlayerStats" and want to make a dataframe of it. I'm not sure how to specify that or exclude the other two result sets. If anyone could help me out with this question that would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this, it worked for me:

```
df <- data.frame( json_data$resultSets[ 1 , "rowSet" ] )

names(df) <- unlist( json_data$resultSets[ 1 , "headers" ] )
```

When working with lists you can use `$` in order to dig down to lower levels.